# Gnome terminal not working (18.04)

Tags: gnome-terminal

All the sudden my gnome-terminal will not open. This all happened after I installed the termite terminal ([here](https://github.com/Corwind/termite-install)) and was trying to change the default term that opens with Ctrl-Alt-T:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

However, I noticed something. The last time I ran this command there were 2 entries for gnome-terminal (like tilix). Now there's only the one:

```
 0            /usr/local/bin/termite            60        auto mode  
 1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode  
 2            /usr/bin/tilix                    30        manual mode  
 3            /usr/bin/tilix.wrapper            30        manual mode
 4            /usr/bin/urxvt                    20        manual mode
*5            /usr/local/bin/termite            60        manual mode
```

And here is the error message I get when trying to run gnome-terminal:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling
StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

I'm really at a loss. I've tried some of the solutions involving locale-gen but to no avail. I've reinstalled gnome-terminal and rebooted, tried different acounts, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, gnome-terminal requires `vte` version 0.52. Termite needs a fork of vte called `vte-ng`, as of writing this comment the newest version of that is 0.50. Probably your gnome-terminal now tries to load vte-ng 0.50 instead of vte 0.52 and fails because it's not recent enough.

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled everything to do with termite (with help from locate) and gnome-terminal works again. Hmm.

Comment: Your answer is okay, but a more in-depth answer what steps to take etc. would possibly earn you upvotes and thus AskUbuntu-Gamification-Points ... and beside that, make it easier for the next user with a similiar problem to follow your step. What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)